# Would a Stored procedure help here?

Tags: ibm-midrange, crystal-reports-xi, db2-400

I have created a VIEW on IBM i, which works and displays in Crystal Reports, however it is in HEX so I had to change the ODBC manager to translate and this is fine on my pc. however, the crystal server is not making this translation. SO i was thinking, if i create a stored procedure which will take this view, and copy it to a DDS based PF, which those type of files have never been a problem with the crystal server.

Is this a reasonable use of stored proc in ibm I?

Comment: Or you could just [fix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) the character encoding on the files.

Comment: This cannot be done on the server because we have no idea how this might impact. What I want to do is copy the view to a PF within a running procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try a more global solution by changing the ODBC connection settings on the crystal server.

You would want to set `TRANSLATE` to 1 in its [connection string settings](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordstranprop.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You could do what you propose.

Is it a reasonable use of a stored procedure?  Definitely not.

You would end up creating these stored procedure hacks for every possible table you could ever access in the future.

Time would be better invested cleaning up the system in the short and long term.

Usually a [CHGPF](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/chgpf.htm) with the correct [CCSID](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/nls/rbagscdra.htm) is all that is required.  A test environment could easily be created to validate the changes before applying them to the production system.

Comment: So, Can I create the view to create a PF then do the CHGPF that would work.